# How do I access my django app running on Amazon ec2?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So, I have looked around stack overflow + other sites, but havent been able to solve this problem: hence posting this question!

I have recently started learning django... and am now trying to run it on ec2.

I have an ec2 instance of this format: ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com on which I have a django app running. I changed the security group of this instance to allow http port 80 connections.

I did try to run it the django app the following ways: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 and python manage.py runserver ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000 and that doesnt seem to be helping either!

To make sure that there is nothing faulty from django's side, I opened another terminal window and ssh'ed into the instance and did a curl GET request to localhost:8000/admin which went through successfully.

Where am I going wrong? Will appreciate any help!

Comment: This might be a port restriction issue. You should make your app run on port 80 or 8080 instead of 8000.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are running the app on port 8000, when that port isn't open on the instance (you only opened port 80).

So either close port 80 and open port 8000 from the security group, or run your app on port 80.

Running any application on a port that is less than 1024 requires root privileges; so if you try to do `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80` as a normal user, you'll get an error.

Instead of doing `sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`, you have a few options:

1. Run a pre-configured AMI image for django (like [this one](http://bitnami.com/stack/django) from bitnami).
2. Configure a front end server to listen on port 80, and then proxy requests to your django application. The common stack here is nginx + gunicorn + supervisor, and [this blog post](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/) explains how to set that up (along with a virtual environment which is always a good habit to get into).

Comment: Worked! THanks Burhan! I thought adding HTTP connections is all thats needed. I needed to add TCP connections on port 8000 to my security group. Works now. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, can curl, can't access the page from the ec2 public dns, I get a 404, nginx error. I have added the tcp rule for port 8000

Comment: I'm faced with exactly the same issue, adding a custom TCP, with port range 8000, source: 0.0.0.0/0 did the magic, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include your IPv4 Public IP address in the ALLOWED_HOSTS section in Django project/app/settings.py script...