# How to configure Elastic IP with django app in aws?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am building an app using django in EC2-ubuntu and i have associated Elastic ip with my instance.

i have done following steps : 
1. first created instance of ubuntu in ec2 free tier.
2. installed python.
3. installed pip.
4. installed django.
5. create a django project using django-admin startproject.
6. run server using these commads python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
7. created an elastic ip and associated to the instance.
8. configure security inbound settings with http 0.0.0.0:80 address.
9. able to ping my project using any browser.

But the problem is when i am closing my putty session where i supplied runserver command, django project is also stopped. i did not stop it manually.
Please, help me to keep on running after closing putty session as well.

Thanks,
Kripa Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921705/how-do-i-access-my-django-app-running-on-amazon-ec2)

I highly recommend that you start using Elastic Beanstalk (Python instance) to take care of all these steps for you. Very simple to setup, and no need to worry about any of the steps you listed.

You can use [this instruction](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) to see how you can deploy a Django app in less than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

You are trying to persist the debug server for a remotely deployed application.

You probably need to review [the `runserver` command documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#runserver). Here are the relevant parts:

> django-admin runserver [addrport]
>
> Starts a lightweight development Web server on the local machine. By default, the server runs on port 8000 on the IP address 127.0.0.1. You can pass in an IP address and port number explicitly.
>
> ...
>
> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

### A webserver

Having skimmed the above docs, you may want to look at ["How to deploy with WSGI" section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/), which gives a few recommendations for commonly used Web servers. My favorite, [Gunicorn](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/), includes a usage example:

```
$ pip install gunicorn
$ gunicorn myproject.wsgi
```

Having decided, and installed a webserver, you'd need to "daemonize" it and expose it to the world.

The former is usually done by creating a service on your OS, for ubuntu it would be either upstart or systemd depending on the version. [Gunicorn docs have examples for both](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#upstart).

The latter is usually achieved with an http-server/proxy such as nginx or apache httpd. And again, [Gunicorn has an example for us](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

You can see why I like it so much ☺️

### Epilogue

While technically possible to run the debug server as a service or even in a terminal multiplexer such as [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/), it's not a recommended or stable long term solution.

That said, these are very useful to know about, so read on the above tools and learn to use them, since they would be invaluable to have in your toolset in the future, for example to avoid accidentally terminating a long running command (such as migration), etc.