# How do I access my Django app hosted on EC2?

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am running a django-based application (Arches) in an AWS EC2 instance, and am unable to access it on either the Public IPv4 address, or the Public IPv4 DNS.

I have tried virtually all combinations of parameters, as well as the steps described in the following discussions:

- [How do I access my Django app running on Amazon EC2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921705/how-do-i-access-my-django-app-running-on-amazon-ec2)
- [Access Django app on AWS EC2 host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577076/access-django-app-on-aws-ec2-host)
- [Connecting to EC2 Django development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865621/connecting-to-ec2-django-development-server)

Without `:8000`

```bash
ec2-xxxxxxxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com refused to connect.
```

With `:8000`

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
ec2-xxxxxxxxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com sent an invalid response.
```

[image]

Terminal output
[image]

Changing the protocol to http gives the following error

```py
OSError at /
Error reading /home/ubuntu/suhozid/suhozid/webpack/webpack-stats.json. Are you sure webpack has generated the file and the path is correct?
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://3.76.192.148:8000/ 
Django Version: 3.2.19
Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:    
Error reading /home/ubuntu/suhozid/suhozid/webpack/webpack-stats.json. Are you sure webpack has generated the file and the path is correct?
Exception Location: /home/ubuntu/dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webpack_loader/loader.py, line 29, in load_assets
Python Executable:  /home/ubuntu/dev/bin/python
Python Version: 3.10.6
Python Path:    
['/home/ubuntu/suhozid',
 '/home/ubuntu/suhozid',
 '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/home/ubuntu/dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
 '/home/ubuntu/suhozid/suhozid']
Server time:    Fri, 16 Jun 2023 04:50:13 -0500
```

And a different terminal output

```
OSError: Error reading /home/ubuntu/suhozid/suhozid/webpack/webpack-stats.json. Are you sure webpack has generated the file and the path is correct?
[16/Jun/2023 05:20:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 160120
```

I was hoping to be able to access my Django app by adding the addresses in `settings.py`

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['3.76.192.148', 'ec2-3-76-192-148.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com']
```